# Best practices for resizing user uploaded images

Tags: php, image, imagemagick, resize, uploading

I am working for a website, with a lot of user uploaded images.

Lets suppose that the designers did a great job and using 4:3 all over the site. So for now, we have 2 sizes, namely 400x300 and 200x150

Which resizing strategy do you think works best for a case like that? If a user uploads an image of 800x200, how should it be resized? should it go to 400x100, or should it go at 1200x300 and then cropped to the center, making it 400x300?

Also what do you think it should happen for smaller images. eg, what if the user tries to upload 200x150 to start with. Should it be scaled up? Some kind of effect applied to it? I dont think all smaller images should be rejected, although if they are too small, the user could get an error message

Btw, i am talking about uploading and processing with PHP (Imagemagick)

Comment: The best practice is to do what your customer/designer wants and what is more appropriate for the specific site. All the scenarios you listed seem good to me generally.

Comment: In our app, we always resize images into square but maintain the original image's aspect ratio i.e. if the original image is not 1:1 to being with, we just pad it. We don't center crop images as I have found a lot of people at least these days follow rule of thirds in photography and the area of interest in a image is generally off-center :).

Comment: So, you keep images in different ratios stored?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should use bicubic filtering when making images smaller, and bilinear filtering when making images larger. Bicubic filter helps with sharpness of the image, while bilinear smoothens the image.

However, whether to crop or resize or mix of the two, it is completely dependent on the type of images your users upload and the way they are displayed on the site.

For example, if you have thumbnails for photographs, you probably would want to avoid cropping them as much as possible.

But if you're looking for a sort of "artistic" feel, it could be fine to crop the image from a corner without actually resizing the image much.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.. what about having images stored in different proportions  than the ones you are using. If on the website, the size is 400x300, and the user uploaded 600x200, what would you think the best thing would be. Scale down 1.5 times to reach the 400 width, or scale up 1.5 times to reach 300 height, and then crop the excess width?

Comment: @NikosZinas I would go with scaling down, as it preserves image quality better than scaling up.